# Is there a way I can higlight cells that are above or belove average but if I can define how much difference can be?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm trying to create formula to higliht cells that are above or below avearge but with permissible deviation, so not higliht immediately but alow +/- custom value

=C4>$O$5*0,002

=C4>$O$5*0,002

=C4>$O$5*0,002

> (from comment)
>
> i'm looking for numbers that exceed an allowed tolerance from the average, lets say I have numbers in range $C$4:$I$7, and I want to higlight just cells that are +2 above average number in same range($C$4:$I$7)

Comment: Use conditional format with a formula - and you have the formula...

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for numbers that exceed an allowed tolerance from the average. Take the absolute of the difference between the number and the average and see if that exceeds your tolerance.

With 'the number' in C4, the 'average' in O5 and the tolerance as 0.002,

```
=ABS(C4-$O$5)>0.002
```

TRUE is outside tolerance; FALSE if within tolerance.

For +2 then select $C$4:$I$7 and create a conditional format with

```
=(C4-average($C$4:$I$7))>2
```

and for ±2 use

```
=abs(C4-average($C$4:$I$7))>2
```

Comment: You are right, i'm looking for numbers that exceed an allowed tolerance from the average, lets say I have numbers in range $C$4:$I$7, and I want to higlight just cells that are +2 above average number in same range($C$4:$I$7)

Comment: +2 or ±2? For +2 then select $C$4:$I$7 and create a conditional format with `=(C4-average($C$4:$I$7))>2` and for ±2 use `=abs(C4-average($C$4:$I$7))>2`

Comment: Wow, user11314630 thank you so much abs forumla worked great!